# Can't figure out an XPath count expression result. C# xml Web Services

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xpath

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
- <OrderFeed>
- <Order id="1">
- <BillingInformation>
  <Name>Bruce Ganek</Name> 
  <Address>99 Main Street</Address> 
  <City>Cranston</City> 
  <State>RI</State> 
  <ZipCode>02910</ZipCode> 
  </BillingInformation>
- <ShippingInformation>
  <Name>Governor Chafee</Name> 
  <Address>82 Smith St # 115</Address> 
  <City>Providence</City> 
  <State>RI</State> 
  <ZipCode>02903-1121</ZipCode> 
  </ShippingInformation>
- <Items>
- <Item>
  <PartNo>JETSWEATER</PartNo> 
  <Description>N.Y. Jets Sweatshirt</Description> 
  <UnitPrice>10.50</UnitPrice> 
  <Quantity>2</Quantity> 
  <TotalCost>21.00</TotalCost> 
- <CustomerOptions>
  <Size>M</Size> 
  <Color>Green</Color> 
  </CustomerOptions>
  </Item>
- <Item>
  <PartNo>JETSWEATER</PartNo> 
  <Description>N.Y. Jets Sweatshirt</Description> 
  <UnitPrice>7.50</UnitPrice> 
  <Quantity>3</Quantity> 
  <TotalCost>22.50</TotalCost> 
- <CustomerOptions>
  <Size>S</Size> 
  <Color>White</Color> 
  </CustomerOptions>
  </Item>
- <Item>
  <PartNo>JETSFLASHLIGHT</PartNo> 
  <Description>N.Y. Jets Flashlight</Description> 
  <UnitPrice>5.00</UnitPrice> 
  <Quantity>1</Quantity> 
  <TotalCost>5.00</TotalCost> 
  <CustomerOptions /> 
  </Item>
  </Items>
  </Order>
- <Order id="2">
- <BillingInformation>
  <Name>Walt Disney</Name> 
  <Address>DisneyWorld Hotel</Address> 
  <City>Orlando</City> 
  <State>FL</State> 
  <ZipCode>32801</ZipCode> 
  </BillingInformation>
- <ShippingInformation>
  <Name>Walt Disney</Name> 
  <Address>DisneyWorld Hotel</Address> 
  <City>Orlando</City> 
  <State>FL</State> 
  <ZipCode>32801</ZipCode> 
  </ShippingInformation>
- <Items>
- <Item>
  <PartNo>JETSWEATER</PartNo> 
  <Description>N.Y. Jets Sweatshirt</Description> 
  <UnitPrice>10.50</UnitPrice> 
  <Quantity>2</Quantity> 
  <TotalCost>21.00</TotalCost> 
- <CustomerOptions>
  <Size>M</Size> 
  <Color>Green</Color> 
  </CustomerOptions>
  </Item>
- <Item>
  <PartNo>JETSWEATER</PartNo> 
  <Description>N.Y. Jets Sweatshirt</Description> 
  <UnitPrice>7.50</UnitPrice> 
  <Quantity>3</Quantity> 
  <TotalCost>22.50</TotalCost> 
- <CustomerOptions>
  <Size>S</Size> 
  <Color>White</Color> 
  </CustomerOptions>
  </Item>
- <Item>
  <PartNo>JETSFLAG</PartNo> 
  <Description>N.Y. Jets Flag for display</Description> 
  <UnitPrice>5.00</UnitPrice> 
  <Quantity>1</Quantity> 
  <TotalCost>5.00</TotalCost> 
  <CustomerOptions /> 
  </Item>
  </Items>
  </Order>
- <Order id="3">
- <BillingInformation>
  <Name>Tom Brady</Name> 
  <Address>One Patriot Place</Address> 
  <City>Foxboro</City> 
  <State>MA</State> 
  <ZipCode>02035</ZipCode> 
  </BillingInformation>
- <ShippingInformation>
  <Name>Tom Brady</Name> 
  <Address>2121 George Halas Drive</Address> 
  <City>Canton</City> 
  <State>OH</State> 
  <ZipCode>44708</ZipCode> 
  </ShippingInformation>
- <Items>
- <Item>
  <PartNo>JETPANTS</PartNo> 
  <Description>N.Y. Jets Sweatpants</Description> 
  <UnitPrice>10.50</UnitPrice> 
  <Quantity>3</Quantity> 
  <TotalCost>31.50</TotalCost> 
- <CustomerOptions>
  <Size>M</Size> 
  <Color>Green</Color> 
  </CustomerOptions>
  </Item>
- <Item>
  <PartNo>JETSWEATER</PartNo> 
  <Description>N.Y. Jets Sweatshirt</Description> 
  <UnitPrice>7.50</UnitPrice> 
  <Quantity>1</Quantity> 
  <TotalCost>7.50</TotalCost> 
- <CustomerOptions>
  <Size>S</Size> 
  <Color>White</Color> 
  </CustomerOptions>
  </Item>
- <Item>
  <PartNo>JETSFLAG</PartNo> 
  <Description>N.Y. Jets Flag for display</Description> 
  <UnitPrice>5.00</UnitPrice> 
  <Quantity>1</Quantity> 
  <TotalCost>5.00</TotalCost> 
  <CustomerOptions /> 
  </Item>
  </Items>
  </Order>
  </OrderFeed>
```

Above is the xml document I am parsing. My objective is to get a use to type in a PartNo, say for example "JETSFLAG" is the string they pass to the application. I want to find all the orders accross the OrderFeed and count the amount of times that PartNo specifically, was bought. I have an XPath Navigator tool that for some reason doesn't return anything when I write the expression that should be working to get me what I want.

This is what I get for a result when I evaluate the expression: `//OrderFeed/Order/Items//Item//PartNo` which gets me the data I need, all I need is the count of any particular item the user inputs...

```
  <xml>JETSWEATER JETSWEATER JETSFLASHLIGHT JETSWEATER JETSWEATER JETSFLAG JETPANTS JETSWEATER JETSFLAG</xml>
```

Now, I'm pretty sure writing `count(//OrderFeed/Order/Items//Item//PartNo[JETSFLAG])` Should result in 2 items being counted. But this is what I get returned to me...

```
  <xml>0</xml>
```

I get 0 returned for a count, when it is displayed. Can someone help?

Answer (score 4):

Try the path:

```
/OrderFeed/Order/Items/Item[PartNo=JETSFLAG]
```

(quoting as appropriate for your environment)

Answer (score 2):

> Now, I'm pretty sure writing `count(//OrderFeed/Order/Items//Item//PartNo[JETSFLAG])` Should result in 2 items being counted. But this is what I get returned to me...
>
> ```
>  <xml>0</xml>
> ```

**There are several problems in the above XPath expression**:

1. `PartNo[JETSFLAG]` means: "Select any `PartNo` element that has a child named `JETSFLAG`". But this isn't what you want -- you actually want: any `PartNo` element, whose string value is the string `"JETSFLAG"` -- so use: `PartNo[. = 'JETSFLAG']`
2. Unnecessary use uf the `//` abbreviation. This is generally expensive and in this particular case you only need the children of the elements selected at each location step -- therefore use just the `/` operator.
3. You can omit the name of the document element, because a well-formed XML document by definition has exactly one document element. So, instead of writing `/OrderFeed` use just `/*`

**Combining all of the above fixes, we arrive at these two XPath expressions, respectively** :

```
/*/Order/Items/Item/PartNo[. = 'JETSFLAG']
```

**and**

```
count(/*/Order/Items/Item/PartNo[. = 'JETSFLAG'])
```

The former selects the two wanted `PartNo` elements.

The latter returns their number:
 `2`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this xpath and it seems to be working.

`count(//OrderFeed/Order/Items/Item[PartNo = 'JETSFLAG'])`

Answer (score 0):

Several people have showed you the XPath expression you need. But beware of injection attacks! You should never construct an XPath expression by concatenating a skeleton expression with user-supplied input, without being aware of the injection risk. Ideally, if you XPath API allows it, use an expression with a variable:

```
count(//OrderFeed/Order/Items/Item[PartNo = $param])
```

and then supply the value of $param via the API.